# Hibernate: @wherejointable to filter subtable

Tags: hibernate, annotations, where-clause

I am already using @where clause to filter soft deleted rows for an entity. (with a 'deleted' flag). This works very well.

Now, I need to filter a linked table that store history of linked item. 
The history strategy, is just to use the max id row of the linked table.
This is what I have now:

```
@Where(clause="deleted = 0" )
EntityA{

   @Column(name = "id")
   Integer id;

   @Column(name = "deleted")
   Integer deleted;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
   List<EntityB> subEntities;
   EntityB getCurrentEntityB(){
       .. loop in java that return the B with the max(id).
   }
}

EntityB{

    @Column(name = "id")
    Integer id;
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
    EntityA a;
}
```

I think that I could simplify this with the @WhereJoinTable annotation, but I am a bit lost with the possibilities.
I tried something like this:

```
@Where(clause="deleted = 0" )
EntityA{
   ...
   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a")
   @WhereJoinTable(clause = "id in( select max(id) from entityB where a_id = :id )")
   EntityB currentEntityB;
}
```

but the syntax is not correct, and I don't really know how to do it...

It is not that easy to find a extensive docs on this feature on the web...

Any help ?

J.